# How to make scopes in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, scope

Using c++ I can write something like this

```
int main(){
   {
      int a;
      //some magic in this scope with a
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Variable a is visible only in the block, where it was created. Is there a way to do the same in Kotlin?

Comment: `run { /* scoped code here */ }`

Comment: oh, so simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Honestly if you have sufficient cohesion of variables to require a limited scope, I would 100% go for extracting a function with a proper name, and never use `run`.

Comment: In addition to extract a method, it's also possible to use [local functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html). So you can keep your magic internal, scoped and even give it a self-explanatory name:  
```fun inlineMagic(a: Int);   inlineMagic(a)```